# Android OCR/Image feature recognition

Tags: java, android, image, ocr, image-recognition

I just picked up a contract for developing an Android app that will be able to recognize specific objects within an image.  Due to the details of the contract I'm working on, I can't provide too many project-specifics, but I'll try to do my best.  It can be assumed that the objects will always be of the same size, color, and perspective.  There are roughly 30 kinds of objects and one input image can contain up to 100 of these objects.  What I need to do is find the exact location of each, as well as which kind of object it is.  There won't be any object overlap in the images.

I don't think I explained this too well, but to give you guys a better idea of what I'm looking for, I think the Cheat Master 5000 app for iPhone (video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3xKu3UkkYo) should provide a great example.  While my project is nothing like this app at all, I think a very similar algorithm could be used for object recognition.

I've been developing mobile apps for a long time, but I'm completely new to image recognition algorithms.  My initial idea was to train an OCR library such as Tesseract or JavaOCR to recognize my objects as pre-defined letters, but I know OCR is fairly slow and probably a lot of overhead for something like what I need.  My next thought was using OpenCV for pattern classification, but this seems pretty complicated and I don't want to spend a ton of time getting it working only to discover that it won't meet our needs.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks, and sorry again for the confusing question...I wish I could have given more detail, but I'm really not allowed to.

Comment: Just ti make it clear, OCR stands for optical character recognition. Do you plan to implement any text recognition features?

Comment: Yep, I know what OCR is.  Like I said, my first plan was to train an OCR library to recognize my objects as characters.  As there are only 30 objects I'll ever be looking for, it wouldn't be hard to map them to letters.  Given that they'll always be the same size and perspective, and will be lined up like letters would be, I think it would work.  It just seemed like it could be a lot of overhead for what I need.